# ASP.NET MVC create and edit one to many relationship invalid modelstate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-many, modelstate

Why does ModelState.IsValid returns "false" when storing one to many data with a post. I'm using ViewModel and EditorTemplate to display those data right for edit. In my case Test(one)-Questions(many). If only test is stored modelstate is valid, but if I store questions with the test the model state becomes invalid... looked all over the place for informaiton, but can't understand why this is not valid. Since many tutorials show this is the way to map one to many relationship, why can't I post data this way?

Model

```
public class Test
{
   public Test()
   {
      this.Questions = new List<Question>();
   }
//some excluded for brevity

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime TestDate { get; set; }

    public int TestTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public virtual Type Type { get; set; }
   }
}

public class Question
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }

    public int TestID { get; set; }

    public string Question { get; set; }

    public virtual Test Test { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel (using a viewmodel, because it helps with generating dropdownlist from the data stored in database)

```
  public class TestData
{
    public Test Test { get; set; }
    public Question Question { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TestType> TestTypes { get; set; }
    public List<string> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

Editor Template for Questions

```
@model Project.Models.CustomQuestion
<div>
 @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.QuestionID)
 @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.TestID)
 @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Test)
 @Html.EditorFor(a => a.Question)
</div>
```

View (for edit)

```
@model  Project.ViewModels.TestData

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Event</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.Test.Id)

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Test.Name
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Test.TestDate)
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Test.TestTypeId, new SelectList(Model.TestTypes, "Id", "Name"))
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        if 5 questions are stored 5 textboxes with questions will appear
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Test.Questions)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {

       var viewModel = new ViewModels.TestData
       {
          Test = db.Tests.Find(id),
          TestTypes = db.TestTypes
       };
           return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(TestData testData)
    {

       if (ModelState.IsValid) //returns "false" if testData.Event.Questions > 0
       {
          db.Entry(testtData).State = EntityState.Modified;
          db.SaveChanges();
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }

       return View(testData);
     }
```

Comment: Have you seen what the error is inside the ModelState?

Comment: use the following to know what the error is
var errors = ModelState.Values.Where(x=>x.Errors.Any());

Comment: I used the code you provided and looked at it in debug... error count =1, error message ='', exception = System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'Project.Models.Test' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.

Comment: again, if I don't include values for questions I get nothing... hmmm

Comment: thank you helping me figure out what's causing this problem! but in my view questions comes from model.test.question, since questions need fk test id... if i simply use model.questions (with question type) it doesn't return anything for the "edit" view. I tired to comment on your answer, but it's no longer there.